# Mapping request when Wrapping graphQL(appsync) with GET REST API using Amazon api gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-appsync

I want to create a **GET** endpoint as a wrapper over an existing App Sync api for a specific query using AWS Service integration in API Gateway.

Eg. `/employee/{id}/residenceCountry`

In the mapping template I put the query as

```
{"query":"query MyQuery {getEmployeeDetails(id: \"$method.request.path.id\") {address {country}}}"}
```

However, I am getting a 500 Internal server error with no proper logs.

When I create a *POST* endpoint such that I pass the above body as request body to my rest api with passthrough, it works.

In the execution logs I see the exact same content for `Endpoint request body after transformations:`

In order to get the proper logs I tried getting `$context.error.message` and `$context.integrationErrorMessage` but I do not get any details.

Could someone please tell what I could be doing wrong or how to debug this better?

Answer (score 1):

It turned out to be a very silly mistake of selecting `App Sync` as AWS Service in GET vs `App Sync Data Plane` in POST. It was only made apparent via another set of eyes. Thanks to my colleague Albert Hoxha.